# Any changes to model binding to dictionary<T1, T2> in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I know that in ASP.NET MVC 1 in order to bind dynamic form values to a dictionary, dictionary keys must be **integer, zero based and non-breaking**. Is it still the case with ASP.NET MVC 2?
I'm struggling to get default model binder to fill the `Dictionary<Guid, Guid[]>` from dynamic checkboxes but can't get it to work. It seems that custom model binder is the only way to go.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: What I'm now doing is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MyDict[{GUID1_KEY}].Key" value = "{GUID1_KEY}"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="MyDict[{GUID1_KEY}].Value" value = "{GUID2_VALUE}"/>
... more such checkboxes that have a hidden backing field with dictionary key and some other value guid.

on the server I expect:

ActionResult PostMe(Dictionary<Guid, Guid[]> dict){..
Where this dictionary should be filled with one key(GUID1) and many values (in array) - GUID2, 3, n.
```

To be precise, in my action method I accept the view model which has a property of Dictionary MyDict, but this is hardly relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Hope [Dictionary Model Binder in ASP.NET MVC2 and MVC3](http://siphon9.net/loune/2010/11/dictionary-model-binder-in-asp-net-mvc2-and-mvc3/) article will be helpful for you.